Iterating a mutate function across different variables in a dataframe
I need a mutate and iterate function that will combine 6 variables(1st to 6th, 7th to 12th…..) and create 1 new combined variable using the sample data set below:
Sample data frame with 75 variables (test 75)
test75 <- data.frame(matrix(sample(0:1, 75 * 6, replace = TRUE), ncol = 75))
names(test75) <- paste0("Q", 1:75)


Hi Jacob, welcome to Stack Overflow. If you could include a sample dataset in your question, perhaps using dput, that would be great thanks. If you could include your desired output, that would be great also

Hi Mark. Welcome. I found a solution. I posted sample data frame with the solution for anyone who has a similar challenge in future.

Please post the solution as an answer, not edited into your question. That way when people browse for your question it will be clear there is an an answer.

Thanks. I made revisions to retain the question and posted the solution as an answer.

#I tried in vain earlier but I found a solution which I have posted below for the same data set.
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(janitor) 

# Sample dataset with a data frame with 75 variables (test 75)
test75 <- data.frame(matrix(sample(0:1, 75 * 6, replace = TRUE), ncol = 75))
names(test75) <- paste0("Q", 1:75)
view(test75)

# 1. Define the transformation function
apply_transformations <- function(df, start) {
  if (start + 5 <= ncol(df)) {  # Ensure there is group of 6 to process
    vars_in_group <- names(df)[start:(start+5)]
    combined_name <- paste0("Q", start, "Combined")
    
    df <- df %>%
      mutate(!!combined_name := case_when(
        !!sym(vars_in_group[1]) == 1 ~ 5,
        !!sym(vars_in_group[2]) == 1 ~ 4,
        !!sym(vars_in_group[3]) == 1 ~ 3,
        !!sym(vars_in_group[4]) == 1 ~ 2,
        !!sym(vars_in_group[5]) == 1 ~ 1,
        !!sym(vars_in_group[6]) == 1 ~ 99,
        TRUE ~ 0
      ))
  }
  return(df)
}

# 2. Calculate appropriate indices to start each group
indices <- seq(1, ncol(test75) - 6, by = 8)

# 3. Apply the function to each group starting index
for (index in indices) {
  test75 <- apply_transformations(test75, index)
}

# Print the resulting data frame to see some of the combined variables
print(head(test75))
view(test75)

